# Condition of for loop in c

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I have an array of characters and I want to make a loop where if the next character of the array is a digit, the loop jumps to the next character, and if not, I print the last digit. Can/should I do this?

```
int h;
char array[20];

for (h=0;isdigit(array[h]);h++)
   h=h+1;
if(!isdigit(array[h]))
printf ("%d",h-1)
```

So far the only conditions I have used with the for loop are "numerical" conditions like "h<=10".

I am programming with C.

Comment: So, you've shown code. Does it compile? Does it work? If not, what are the expected and actual results?

Comment: You start by looking at `array`, then suddenly switch to looking at `expression` (which was not declared).  Huh??

Comment: Yes sorry, I wanted to put array, not expression. I don't know if it compile, I am wondering if as a condition in a for loop i can put isdigit(array[h]

Answer (score 2):

Here's my analysis of your code:

```
int h;
char array[20];

for (h=0;isdigit(array[h]);h++)
   h=h+1;
if(!isdigit(expression[h]))      // "expression" is not declared.
    printf ("%d",h-1)            // Missing Semicolon
```

---

As for what you can put in the middle part of the for-loop:
Anything that will evaluate to True/False.
And in C, 0 is the same as False, and any other number is True.
`isdigit` returns a number indicating true/false, so it works just fine.

---

Here's what I think you meant:

```
int h;
char array[20];

for (h=0;isdigit(array[h]);h++) /**/; // While you have digits, go to the next character.

// Now that the loop is over:
printf ("%c",array[h-1]); // Print the previous character
```

Comment: To prevent out of bounds the condition within the loop should be `isdigit(array[h]) && h<20` .

Comment: Assuming he will check that he doesn't run out of the bounds of the array shouldn't the final `if(!isdigit(array[h]))` be left in? What if the for loop hits the end of the array and then prints the last element of the array when it isn't a digit?